# OData $orderBy with nested $filter and $top

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an OData endpoint and want to order the results based on a property `Sort` of the first entry in a nested collection.

It boils down to translate the following LINQ query to OData syntax.

```
TblProduktFacts
.OrderBy(f => f.TblProduktFactZuors.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Sort > 0 && z.TblProduktKlasseSubId == 123).Sort)
```

However I'm failing at translating the `FirstOrDefault()`

I tried the following

```
$orderby=TblProduktFactZuors($filter=Sort gt 0 and TblProduktKlasseSubId eq 1175;$top=1)/Sort
```

This results in this exception

> Microsoft.OData.ODataException: Syntax error: character ';' is not valid at position 71 in 'TblProduktFactZuors($filter=Sort gt 0 and TblProduktKlasseSubId eq 1175;$top=1)/Sort'.

I also tried ommiting the `$filter` part

```
$orderby=TblProduktFactZuors($top=1)/Sort
```

But this will give me the following exception

> Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An unknown function with name 'TblProduktFactZuors' was found. This may also be a function import or a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed.

Does anyone know how the correct OData syntax for that order-by-clause is?

Comment: After removing the `/Sort` at the end of the query options, whether it works or not? From [this article](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/), we can see that `$orderby` parameter is the column, so, you might need to expand and filter the data first, then,  sort the result. To query the nested object, you could try to use the `$expand` syntax. Besides, can you show the model definition and create a sample (include the test data, and what result you expect to achieve), it might be easier for us to reproduce the problem and fix it.

Comment: `TblProduktFactZuors` is a navigation property to the table `TblProduktFactZuor`. Sort is an `int` property on `TblProduktFactZuor`. Removing the `/Sort` from the end results in the same exception as with the `/Sort`.